# JavaFX- can't change style for a TextArea with ToggleButtons

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to make a basic text editor and add some standard options like bold and italic.

I made the "styleSetter" function below, but only the first call (i.e. the first ToggleButton) does what it's supposed to do. The other's don't  do a thing, although they do seem to change the textarea's style attribute to the given String.
I hope i've explained myself well enough, what am i doing wrong?

```
public void styleSetter(ToggleButton tb, TextArea ta , String on, String off){
    if(tb.isSelected()) {
        ta.setStyle(on);
    } else {
        ta.setStyle(off);
    }
}
@FXML public void onBold(){
    model.styleSetter(bold, textArea, "-fx-font-weight: bold", "-fx-font-weight: normal");
}

@FXML public void onItalic(){
    model.styleSetter(italic, textArea, "-fx-font-style: italic", "-fx-font-style: normal");
}

@FXML public void onStrikeThrough(){
    model.styleSetter(strikeThrough, textArea, "-fx-strikethrough: true", "-fx-strikethrough: false");
}

@FXML public void onUnderline(){
    model.styleSetter(underline, textArea, "-fx-underline: true", "-fx-underline: false");
}
```

Comment: Did you add a log entry in the styleSetter method to see if it gets called eveyr time the toggle button is pressed?

Comment: Can you show the code that calls the styleSetter method?

Comment: Why `model.styleSetter` instead of `this.styleSetter`???

Comment: @fabian I'm sorry this wasn't clear. Stylesetter is in de ControllerModel class, the fxml functions are in the Controller class. I have an instance of the model class in the controller class (ControllerModel model =new ControllerModel())

Comment: @jose martinez As i explained to fabian. The FXML methods here are the calls to the stylesetter class. I tried added a system.out to the stylesetter method to show textarea.getStyle and it was the expected css string. Maybe it's somethjng to do with the togglebuttons? Ii have them nested in an hbox, maybe somehow you can't have multiple togglebuttons do stuff eventhough they're not in a togglegroup? Like, tthey're somehow linked automatically?

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly